# Trying to print a word from a String on seperate lines

Tags: java, string, replace

I want it so that it prints each word on its own line.

```java
String movie = "10 Things I Hate About You";
String g = "";
for (int letter = 0; letter < movie.length(); letter++) {
    if (letter != ' ') {
        g += word.charAt(letter);
    } else {
        g += "\n";
    }
}
System.out.println(g);
```

However, I am getting thrown this error each time.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at MyProgram.main(MyProgram.java:34)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check `movie.charAt(letter) != ' '` and if it is `true`, you should add `movie.charAt(letter)` to `g`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String movie = "10 Things I Hate About You";
        String g = "";
        for (int letter = 0; letter < movie.length(); letter++) {
            if (movie.charAt(letter) != ' ') {
                g += movie.charAt(letter);
            } else {
                g += "\n";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(g);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
10
Things
I
Hate
About
You
```

### A much simpler solution:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String movie = "10 Things I Hate About You";
        movie = movie.replace(' ', '\n');
        System.out.println(movie);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
10
Things
I
Hate
About
You
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String movie = "10 Things I Hate About You";
StringBuilder g = new StringBuilder();
String g = "";
for(int letter = 0; letter < movie.length(); letter++) {
    if(word.charAt(letter) != ' ') {
        g.append(word.charAt(letter));
    }
    else {
        g.append("\n");
    }
}System.out.println(g);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into an array and print each element of that array in a new line.

```
String movie = "One word per line";
String[] arrOfStr = movie.split(" ");
for(String s : arrOfStr){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to split the array.  No need for loops to check individual characters.  This uses the line separator relevant to the operating system that you are using.

```
String movie = "10 Things I Hate About You";
movie = movie.replaceAll(" ", System.getProperty("line.separator"));

System.out.println(movie);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner for doing the same thing.

```
System.out.println(movie.replaceAll(" ", "\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

*one line with a lambda:*

```
System.out.print(
    Stream.of( movie.split( " " ) ).collect( Collectors.joining( "\n" ) )
 );
```

`joining(…)` works internally with a `java.util.StringJoiner`

*…a lambda that follows the original `char` by `char` approach:*

```
movie.codePoints().forEach( c
    -> System.out.print( c == ' ' ? '\n' : (char)c ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Tou can use [`String.replace(char,char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) method:

```java
String movie = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
String mov = movie.replace(' ', '\n');
System.out.println(mov);
```

Output:

```
Lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
```